# Cakephp utf8 encoding work only in layout

Tags: cakephp, encoding, utf-8

In my cakephp website special character was replaced  by "�". But not in the layout.

I have already tried:

- apache is configured to serve **utf-8**
- converted database to **utf8_general_ci** collation
- first line of bootstrap.php: **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');**
- core.php: **Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');**
- in database.php: **'encoding' => 'utf8'** while creating database connection
- in layout : **$this->Html->charset();**

[Example on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuk4P.png)

Comment: What if you check your source code (with Firebug for example) ?
Anything in logs ?

Comment: You forgot the only really important thing.. You need to save your files as utf8 otherwise all your attempts will always fail.

Comment: I does'nt have anything in logs and I have no error in the console. And my files are saved in utf-8 without bom.

Comment: you convert db to utf8_general_ci collation, but not old content wich is saved with other encoding. All new content will be saved and display normaly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562023/cakephp-3-1-rc1-utf-8-special-chars-output

Comment: Okay but this text was in my view, not in my db.

Comment: The text from my database was correctly display. But not the text from my files.